# side bar not responsive and overlapping footer

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

My side bar floating navigation is overlapping the footer and is not resizing if viewed from a Laptop with MDPI screen, IPAD Pro or any devices with medium sized screen.

https://barcoak1.pages.op-bit.nz/help/ It can be viewed from here.

Comment: I look at the website, it seems you're using negative margin to position the sidebar, try using left and top, it might work better

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It repositions the side bar and make it visible by setting the `top`, `left` and `z-index` attributes for `.sidebar-nav-fixed`.

```
.sidebar-nav-fixed {
  width: 14%;
  height: 20%;
  /* margin-left: -10%; */
  /* margin-bottom: -5%; */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

If you want to make the side bar more responsive in different screen sizes, you could make use of [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

See the screen shot of the effect of the solution below.

[image]

Comment: I have tried that, it overlaps with the navigation now.

Comment: @LittleNinja I've just uploaded a screen shot for my solution. Does that look the same with what you got with my code?

Comment: it does if its on the middle of the page. try scrolling through the header picture, it overlaps with the sidebar.

Comment: It depends on how you want the elements are positioned. Actually I found that the end goal of the layout for that side bar was not specified. Could you provide more detail about that?

Comment: should just stick on the side of the body(blog thing) rather than overlapping with header,footer, body or anything.on the side part, maybe a wee bit on the middle of the white space on left side.